# Sound not working HDA-Intel Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: sound

Tried all the other "sound not working" posts i think, lost count.

purge/reinstall alsa and pulse, reboot, add user to audio group, various lines in the alsa config file such as "options snd-hda-intel model=" then tried different options like generic, auto, basic, default, etc. tried pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload a few times, with and without rebooting.

Hardware: 16gb ram, core I7-4790, Intel Haswell mboard with onboard sound and graphics
Multimedia: Audio Adapter: HDA-Intel-HDA Intel HDMI
OS: Ubuntu server 14.04 with ubuntu-desktop installed.

**GUI**
sound settings lists only the dummy sound card

**alsamixer -c 0**

```
│ Card: HDA Intel HDMI                                 F1:  Help               │
│ Chip: Intel Haswell HDMI                             F2:  System information │
│ View: F3:[Playback] F4: Capture  F5: All             F6:  Select sound card  │
│ Item: S/PDIF                                                                 │
│                                     ┌──┐                                     │
│                                     │OO│                                     │
│                                     └──┘                                     │
│                                  < S/PDIF >                                  │
```

**aplay -l**

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

**aplay -L**

```
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
hdmi:CARD=HDMI,DEV=0
    HDA Intel HDMI, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
dmix:CARD=HDMI,DEV=3
    HDA Intel HDMI, HDMI 0
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=HDMI,DEV=3
    HDA Intel HDMI, HDMI 0
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=HDMI,DEV=3
    HDA Intel HDMI, HDMI 0
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=HDMI,DEV=3
    HDA Intel HDMI, HDMI 0
    Hardware device with all software conversions
```

**cat /proc/asound/cards**

```
 0 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel HDMI
                      HDA Intel HDMI at 0xf7d14000 irq 46
```

**cat /proc/asound/devices**
  1:        : sequencer
  2: [ 0- 3]: digital audio playback
  3: [ 0- 0]: hardware dependent
  4: [ 0]   : control
 33:        : timer

**mplayer -ao alsa:device=hdmi /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/system-ready.ogg**

```
MPlayer 1.1-4.8 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team
mplayer: could not connect to socket
mplayer: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/system-ready.ogg.
libavformat version 54.20.4 (external)
Mismatching header version 54.20.3
libavformat file format detected.
[lavf] stream 0: audio (vorbis), -aid 0
Load subtitles in /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/
==========================================================================
Opening audio decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg/libavcodec audio decoders
libavcodec version 54.35.0 (external)
AUDIO: 44100 Hz, 1 ch, floatle, 80.0 kbit/5.67% (ratio: 10000->176400)
Selected audio codec: [ffvorbis] afm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg Vorbis)
==========================================================================
[AO_ALSA] alsa-lib: confmisc.c:768:(parse_card) cannot find card '1'
[AO_ALSA] alsa-lib: conf.c:4248:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
[AO_ALSA] alsa-lib: confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
[AO_ALSA] alsa-lib: conf.c:4248:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
[AO_ALSA] alsa-lib: confmisc.c:1251:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
[AO_ALSA] alsa-lib: conf.c:4248:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
[AO_ALSA] alsa-lib: conf.c:4727:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
[AO_ALSA] alsa-lib: pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM hdmi
[AO_ALSA] Playback open error: No such file or directory
Failed to initialize audio driver 'alsa:device=hdmi'
Could not open/initialize audio device -> no sound.
Audio: no sound
Video: no video

Exiting... (End of file)
```

**mplayer -ao alsa:device=hw=0.3 /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/system-ready.ogg**

```
MPlayer 1.1-4.8 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team
mplayer: could not connect to socket
mplayer: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/system-ready.ogg.
libavformat version 54.20.4 (external)
Mismatching header version 54.20.3
libavformat file format detected.
[lavf] stream 0: audio (vorbis), -aid 0
Load subtitles in /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/
==========================================================================
Opening audio decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg/libavcodec audio decoders
libavcodec version 54.35.0 (external)
AUDIO: 44100 Hz, 1 ch, floatle, 80.0 kbit/5.67% (ratio: 10000->176400)
Selected audio codec: [ffvorbis] afm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg Vorbis)
==========================================================================
[AO_ALSA] Format floatle is not supported by hardware, trying default.
AO: [alsa] 44100Hz 2ch s16le (2 bytes per sample)
Video: no video
Starting playback...
A:   0.4 (00.4) of 0.8 (00.7)  0.1% 

Exiting... (End of file)
```

Thank you for your time and help :)

---

UPDATE: I have now added a Creative Soundblaster play 2 USB sound card and disabled the onboard from the BIOS. On my Ubuntu desktop it works right away so the hardware works for sure. On the server its not doing anything. Still only a dummy output in the sound settings (pulse).

reinstalled/purged/etc but to no avail.

alsamixer is not opening at all any more, proc/asound doesn't exist

```
sudo aplay -l
aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found...

lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8534
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    Memory at f7d10000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 8cb1 (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8534

find /lib/modules/`uname -r` | grep snd
(nothing)
```

Comment: have you tried unmuting with alsamixer in command-line? 14.04 comes muted for some reason. Happened on my machine and on other peoples

Comment: i have, the spdif item (there is no volume bar) goes from 00 to MM and back, but neither state provides any sound.

Comment: Do you have only hdmi output(audio from display port) ? The problem could be ( if you have windows8 dual boot  ) the main sound device is frozen . Then you have to shutdown computer from windows8, rebooting is not enough.If still not ok, try to post alsa info result: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/AlsaInfo

Comment: there is headphone socket on the front and in/out/mic ports on the back. the headphone and back "out" port dont work.

It is a single boot system, only ubuntu. go all the way i say, no halfsies :P

alsa info: http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=08b34a4e62b89acc7f8a774fb4b91bdf001b548e

Comment: from alsa-info, the main sound card "Intel Corporation Device 8ca0"  gives a "no codec found" message in syslog  . Silly but try to power off your pc if not done. Else look here : http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=115756 : a similar hardware and problem solved by  a bios update  . Finally, if you have time, report bug in launchpad...

Comment: See update above, and new alsa-info: http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=d3631fe2e8bdfd3c6485d927976d83a3f0de6d9d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved by reverting to older kernel.....

Comment: Could you tell us which one?