# Headset not working in Ubuntu 16.04 on iMac

Tags: 16.04

I install Ubuntu 16.04 on iMac and headphone jack produces no sound.

I read the answers to the following questions but these solutions does not work on iMac!

- [No sound device detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882198/no-sound-device-detected)
- [Laptop headphone jack produces no sound](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768463/laptop-headphone-jack-produces-no-sound)
- [Sound not working HDA-Intel Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/515656/sound-not-working-hda-intel-ubuntu-14-04)

How do I enable headphone jack produces on iMac?